# Return body of Outlook olItem.Class = olDocument

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to access the body of an object from the Outlook's `olItem.Class = olDocument`.

My understanding is the `olItems(i).body` is being deprecated but even if it weren't returns a blank string of length 0.

I tried to save the mail object as a message object with the `.saveas` method but that also didn't save to a file location.

```vb
Sub getMail()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrHeader As Variant
   
    Dim olNS As Namespace
    Dim olInboxFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim olItems As items
    Dim olItem As Variant
    Dim filepath As String
   
    Set olNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInboxFolder = olNS.PickFolder
    Set olItems = olInboxFolder.items
 
    i = 1
   
    For Each olItem In olItems
       
        ' MailItem
        If olItem.Class = olDocument Then 'Debug.Print olItem.Class ==>41            
            debug.print olItems(i).body 'produces string of zero length
            debug.print 'oMail.HTMLBody ==>  'object doesn't support this property or method
        End If
       
        i = i + 1
    Next olItem
   
    Set olItems = Nothing
    Set olInboxFolder = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`DocumentItem.Body` is simply empty - what Outlook shows are the contents of the file. If you want the file contents, save the attachment (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`) from the  `DocumentItem.Attachments` collection - there will always be one attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Appears `If olItem.Class = olDocument` is an attempt to work around a non-existent problem.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub getMail_ForEachLoop()
    
    Dim olInboxFolder As Folder
    
    Dim olItems As Items
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim oMail As mailItem
    
    Set olInboxFolder = Session.PickFolder
    Set olItems = olInboxFolder.Items
    
    For Each olItem In olItems
    
        If olItem.Class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print olItem.Body
            Debug.Print olItem.htmlbody
            
            Set oMail = olItem
            Debug.Print oMail.Body
            Debug.Print oMail.htmlbody
        End If
        
    Next olItem
   
    Set olItems = Nothing
    Set olInboxFolder = Nothing

End Sub

Sub getMail_IndexedLoop()

    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim olInboxFolder As Folder
    
    Dim olItems As Items
    Dim oMail As mailItem
    
    Set olInboxFolder = Session.PickFolder
    Set olItems = olInboxFolder.Items
    
    For i = 1 To olItems.count
       
        If olItems(i).Class = olMail Then
            
            Debug.Print olItems(i).Body
            Debug.Print olItems(i).htmlbody
            
            Set oMail = olItems(i)
            Debug.Print oMail.Body
            Debug.Print oMail.htmlbody
            
        End If
        
    Next i
   
    Set olItems = Nothing
    Set olInboxFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```